# Regexp, Python and doc comments <!-- text -->

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am programing in Python 2.7, I am using beautifulsoup4 to extract information from tags of series of documents. However the document has as well strings as:

```
<!-- PJG ITAG l=90 g=1 f=4 -->
```

And I want to get rid of them, however I am not an expert on regexps. Can someone help with this please?

Comment: If you are using beautiful soup, you should forget about the regexp. beautiful soup should either ignore the comments or give them a special class, which you can simply filter out.

Answer (score 3):

Start by loading your HTML in BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_html)
```

Then, remove all the comments:

```
comments = soup.find_all(text = lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
for comment in comments:
    comment.extract()
```